# Theming a custom user field on register form

Tags: 7, users, theming

I have added a checkbox list field on the register form and I want to change the template for that field.

I have used `field--field-checkbox-list.tpl.php` and `MYTHEME_field__field_checkbox-list()` function, but with no luck on `user_register_form`.

Comment: Are those full names of file and function you used?

Comment: I have edited the question and added the field names also. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two possibilities.  You could alter the form element with hook_field_widget_form_alter, or you could override theme_checkbox.

More info: http://drupal.org/node/173880